# Informix to HiveQL

Tags: sql, join, hive, hiveql, informix

I have a SQL query written for Informix

```
SELECT cols
FROM table1 t1, outer(table2 t2, table3 t3)
WHERE t1.id = t2.id and t2.type = t3.type
```

We have the same tables and data on Hive and I want to translate it to HiveQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informix-style outer joins are quite interesting, and unique, and totally non-standard.  Informix's implementation of ANSI (ISO) standard SQL outer joins should be totally boring and the same as other DBMS.

Here is an SQL script that creates and populates 3 tables and executes 5 different queries against those tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id      SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    data    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    id      INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    info    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id, type)
);

CREATE TABLE table3
(
    type    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name    VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(100, 'Table 1 - ID 100');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(101, 'Table 1 - ID 101');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(102, 'Table 1 - ID 102');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(103, 'Table 1 - ID 103');
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(104, 'Table 1 - ID 104');

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(100, 300, 'Table 2 - ID 100, Type 300');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(100, 301, 'Table 2 - ID 100, Type 301');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(100, 302, 'Table 2 - ID 100, Type 302');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(101, 301, 'Table 2 - ID 101, Type 301');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(101, 400, 'Table 2 - ID 101, Type 400');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(101, 302, 'Table 2 - ID 101, Type 302');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(103, 302, 'Table 2 - ID 103, Type 302');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(103, 303, 'Table 2 - ID 103, Type 303');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(103, 300, 'Table 2 - ID 103, Type 300');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(107, 300, 'Table 2 - ID 107, Type 300');
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(107, 400, 'Table 2 - ID 107, Type 400');

INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(300, 'Table 3 - Type 300');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(301, 'Table 3 - Type 301');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(302, 'Table 3 - Type 302');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(303, 'Table 3 - Type 303');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(304, 'Table 3 - Type 304');
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(305, 'Table 3 - Type 305');
```

```sql
SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1, OUTER(table2 t2, table3 t3)
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.type = t3.type;

SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1, OUTER(table2 t2, OUTER table3 t3)
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.type = t3.type;

SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type;

SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, s.join_key as t2_id, s.t2_type, s.info, s.t3_type, s.name
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT t2.id AS join_key, t2.info, t3.name, t2.type as t2_type, t3.type as t3_type
          FROM table2 t2
          JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type
       ) s ON s.join_key = t1.id;

SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type;
```

The first query is the one from the question, with the selected column names specified.  The list of column names is the same in every query.

The second query is a variant, using an extra OUTER keyword.  It corresponds to the third query, which was the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70197207/1) created by [leftjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700344/leftjoin).  The third query is the first query produced by @leftjoin.  The fourth query is the ['current answer'](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/70197207/3) (strictly, the third revision) created by @leftjoin.  The fifth query is a variation on the fourth — it produces a different answer, so it is not equivalent.

These are the outputs of the queries.

#### Query 1

```sql
SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1, OUTER(table2 t2, table3 t3)
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.type = t3.type;
```

| t1_id | data | t2_id | t2_type | info | t3_type | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 102 | Table 1 - ID 102 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 303 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 303 | 303 | Table 3 - Type 303 |
| 104 | Table 1 - ID 104 |  |  |  |  |  |

#### Query 2

```sql
SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1, OUTER(table2 t2, OUTER table3 t3)
 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.type = t3.type;
```

| t1_id | data | t2_id | t2_type | info | t3_type | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 400 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 400 |  |  |
| 102 | Table 1 - ID 102 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 303 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 303 | 303 | Table 3 - Type 303 |
| 104 | Table 1 - ID 104 |  |  |  |  |  |

#### Query 3

```sql
SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  LEFT JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type;
```

| t1_id | data | t2_id | t2_type | info | t3_type | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 400 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 400 |  |  |
| 102 | Table 1 - ID 102 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 303 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 303 | 303 | Table 3 - Type 303 |
| 104 | Table 1 - ID 104 |  |  |  |  |  |

#### Query 4

```sql
SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, s.join_key as t2_id, s.t2_type, s.info, s.t3_type, s.name
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN 
       (SELECT t2.id AS join_key, t2.info, t3.name, t2.type as t2_type, t3.type as t3_type
          FROM table2 t2
          JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type
       ) s ON s.join_key = t1.id;
```

| t1_id | data | t2_id | t2_type | info | t3_type | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 102 | Table 1 - ID 102 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 303 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 303 | 303 | Table 3 - Type 303 |
| 104 | Table 1 - ID 104 |  |  |  |  |  |

#### Query 5

```sql
SELECT t1.id as t1_id, t1.data, t2.id as t2_id, t2.type as t2_type, t2.info, t3.type as t3_type, t3.name
  FROM table1 t1
  LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  JOIN table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type;
```

| t1_id | data | t2_id | t2_type | info | t3_type | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 300 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 300 | 300 | Table 3 - Type 300 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 301 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 301 | 301 | Table 3 - Type 301 |
| 100 | Table 1 - ID 100 | 100 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 100, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 101 | Table 1 - ID 101 | 101 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 101, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 302 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 302 | 302 | Table 3 - Type 302 |
| 103 | Table 1 - ID 103 | 103 | 303 | Table 2 - ID 103, Type 303 | 303 | Table 3 - Type 303 |

Unless I've missed something, the outputs from Q1 and Q4 are the same (so the answer by @leftjoin is correct); the outputs from the other queries are all different from each other (and from Q1 and Q4).

Answer (score 2):

Use LEFT JOINs instead of OUTER

```
SELECT cols
FROM table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN 
         (select t2.id as join_key, other_cols 
            from table2 t2
                 inner join table3 t3 ON t2.type = t3.type
         ) s ON s.join_key=t1.id
```

Comment: What you've written is close but it corresponds to `FROM table1 t1, OUTER(table2 t2, OUTER table3 t3)`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks, Does it look correct now?

Comment: Yes, that's what it should be.